# How can I run this sql script without using 'go'?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a script that creates and populates tables, and then create the stored procedures for my app to access them. My script runs just fine until I get to the stored procedures. I'm trying to read a .sql file into my app and then run this script through my connection in one execution. Is there any way I can remove the 'go' keyword from this chunk of the script to make it run in one execution?

```
if object_id('GetStudentByID') is not null
drop procedure GetStudentByID;
go
create procedure GetStudentByID
(@StudentID INT)
as
select StudentID,FirstName,LastName
from Student
where StudentID = @StudentID;
```

Comment: why not just split it up to two seperate sql queries?

Comment: Because there will be several stored procs like this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like This:

```
if object_id('GetStudentByID') is not null
    EXEC('drop procedure GetStudentByID;');

EXEC('create procedure GetStudentByID
(@StudentID INT)
as
select StudentID,FirstName,LastName
from Student
where StudentID = @StudentID;');
```

---

This is a common problem because, although it's not immediately apparent, "GO" is *not* a SQL Server command.  Rather it is a command implemented by Management Studio (and SQLCMD as well), to allow you to tell it how to divide up a stream of SQL command text into separate compilable batches.

As SQL Server itself has no such command, you have to go about it differently in cases where you need a SQL Script to fit within a stored procedure, Agent Job, etc.  The SOP way to do this is via dyanmic SQL using either **sp_executeCmd(...)** or  **EXEC('string')** (as above).

Answer (score 0):

You have to have CREATE PROCEDURE in a single batch. I am not sure what you want to achieve. 
Do you want to execute a single command because you can't program the app to execute multiple times? If so then try to set up a loop for each procedure (post back code here if you can't get it to work :))

If you want to execute them together so they all fail or succeed together at the same point in time then wrap them in a transaction. Then you can keep the GO batch separators but they will wait until the end to commit them all.

e.g

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
GO

if object_id('GetStudentByID') is not null
drop procedure GetStudentByID;
go
create procedure GetStudentByID
(@StudentID INT)
as
select StudentID,FirstName,LastName
from Student
where StudentID = @StudentID;
GO
/* replace this line with other procedures */

COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
GO
```

Comment: A loop is what I am currently using to do this. I was mainly just curious whether or not there is a way to get away from the 'go' keyword when doing this process. I'm reading in a .sql file and splitting at the 'go' keyword, and then looping. I just wanted to know if there is a cleaner way to do this or not.